# Post Image to twitter from iphone by xcode

Tags: iphone, twitter, twitpic

I am able to post text from iphone to twitter with `[_engine sendUpdate:[textfield text]];`

But I have to post an image. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

MGTwitter engine doesnt support image uploading, but you could either use this:
https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine

or integrate that into MGTwitter engine.

> Also, please state more information
>   about what library you are using so
>   that people can help YOU. People
>   cannot help you if they have no idea
>   about what you are referring to. It is only since I knew the API you are calling that I could help you.

Comment: I was referring to library you are using.

Comment: I too have to post the local image to twitter which I have attached to view statically.

Comment: Am using the library Twitter+OAuth

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 self.title = @"Causes";

 
 if(_engine) return;
 
 _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
 _engine.consumerKey = @"PzkZj9g57ah2bcB58mD4Q";
 _engine.consumerSecret = @"OvogWpara8xybjMUDGcLklOeZSF12xnYHLE37rel2g";
 
 UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];
 
 if (controller) 
  [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
 else {
  tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [self updateStream:nil];
 }
}

Comment: if ([NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
         returningResponse:&response error:&error] != nil)
  NSLog(@"Posted to Twitter successfully.");
 else 
  NSLog(@"Error posting to Twitter."); 
 [textfield resignFirstResponder];
 [_engine sendUpdate:[textfield text]];
 [self updateStream:nil];

Answer (score -1):

For upload image you should use TwitPic. and use check [this](https://github.com/kimptoc/MGTwitterEngine-1.0.8-OAuth/)

Thanks